# Phone number formatter UI Hint MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, formatting, phone-number

I am trying to format the return value of some string in my model to look more like a phone number...

```
(000)-000-0000
```

I thought I would use a `UIHint` attribute to accomplish this.  The only thing is I am a little confused about how to do this correctly...

How would I pull out the model and format it as a phone number in MVC?

**This is what I am currently trying**

```
@if(Model != null){
    String.Format("{0: (###) ###-####}", Model);
}
```

Right now, it is nuking all non null phone numbers.

**WHAT My model looks like**

```
...
[UIHint("_PhoneNumFormatter")]
        public string PatientRoomPhone { get; set; }
...
```

For instance I take this

```
@if (Model == "0"){
    <text>No</text>
}
else if(Model =="1"){
    <text>Yes</text>  
}
else{
    <text></text>
}
```

use it above a a string that gets back a zero or a one

```
    [UIHint("YesNo")]
    public string DischargeAdvocateCall { get; set; }
```

and viola, I have a UI hint.

Why is that impossible for a Phone number?

Comment: this is rather open-ended. The UI Hint can be used to pair a Partial with your data to render it, but from there you have to decide how to perform rendering. You can use Regex, you can break the field into three fields, etc

Comment: I'll update my post with what I am trying...

Comment: is the model a string? or does the model contain a string?

Comment: the model contains a string

Comment: not to beat a dead horse, but do u mean the model contains a string model.phonenum, or model is string like @model is of type string?

Comment: contains a string... Which is a property of the model...  I'll show you.

Comment: please add the model to your Post

Comment: The model is kind of large.  That is the property that I want to display as a phone number... How can I do that with a UI hint?